# Trying to get the triggers associated with the table with a different schema name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the triggers of the table using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT c.text 
FROM dbo.sysobjects s, dbo.syscomments c
WHERE s.name = 'redgate.tablecampare' 
  AND s.id = c.id
```

This works for `dbo` but not for different schema names

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or greater, this should work:

```
select m.definition
from sys.triggers as t
join sys.sql_modules as m
    on m.object_id = t.object_id
where t.parent_id = object_id('schema.object')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below system catalog to find out triggers containing a specific table.

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) 
    FROM SYSCOMMENTS 
    WHERE [text] LIKE '%redgate.tablecampare%' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTrigger') = 1 
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsTrigger') = 1
    AND definition LIKE '%redgate.tablecampare%'
```